# Determining a probability density function from histogrammed data

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-function

Data on a set of dwell times has been taken and the histogram of which has been fitted with the function:

$$Ae^\frac {-t}{\tau_1} + Be^\frac {-t}{\tau_2}$$

where A is positive and B is negative.

Does this relate to a certain probability distribution? The final aim is to generate random numbers in a simulation which follow this form, for which the only method I know is to calculate a cumulative distribution function from the PDF and use its inverse.